# Improve speed of populating VBA ListBox

Tags: sql, excel, vba, listbox, recordset

Looking for a way to improve the performance of populating a VBA Listbox on a userform in Excel.  I've created a function to connect to a SQL database, query the data I need and create a recordset which I loop through to populate the ListBox.  The query and data retrieval itself seems to fast, the slowness seems to be the method of populating the ListBox control.  I've tried 2 approaches, currently using an array as it was slightly faster.

Its taking 13-14 seconds to populate only 50 rows in the ListBox. Way too long.

```vb
Function GetComments(intRFQ_ID As Integer) As Integer

Dim dbCmnd As ADODB.Command
Dim dbConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rstSQLquery As ADODB.Recordset
Set dbCmnd = New ADODB.Command
Set dbConn = New ADODB.Connection

AA_SQL_Vars
dbConn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};server=" & strDBserver & ";uid=" & strDBuser & ";pwd=" & strDBpass & ";database=" & strDBname
dbConn.Open

frmCommentsView.ListBox1.Clear
ListCnt = 0
RmkCnt = 0
strSQLSelect = ""
strSQLSelect = strSQLSelect & "SELECT [Created],[Comments],[Created_By] "
strSQLSelect = strSQLSelect & "FROM [dbPricing].[dbo].[tblRFQ_Comments] "
strSQLSelect = strSQLSelect & "Where [RFQ_ID] = '" & intRFQ_ID & "'"
strSQLSelect = strSQLSelect & "Order by [Created]"
Set rstSQLquery = New ADODB.Recordset
rstSQLquery.Open strSQLSelect, dbConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

'This is slightly faster
lngRecords = rstSQLquery.RecordCount
If lngRecords > 0 Then
    ReDim strRecords(lngRecords - 1, 3)
    While Not rstSQLquery.EOF
        RmkCnt = RmkCnt + 1
            strRecords(ListCnt, 0) = Format(rstSQLquery.Fields("Created").Value, "YYMMDD HHMM")
            strRecords(ListCnt, 1) = Trim(rstSQLquery.Fields("Comments").Value)
            strRecords(ListCnt, 2) = Trim(rstSQLquery.Fields("Created_By").Value)
        ListCnt = ListCnt + 1
        rstSQLquery.MoveNext
    Wend
    frmCommentsView.ListBox1.List() = strRecords
Else
    frmCommentsView.ListBox1.Clear
End If

'' WHY IS THIS SO SLOW????
'While (Not (rstSQLquery.EOF))
'    RmkCnt = RmkCnt + 1
'    frmCommentsView.ListBox1.AddItem
'    If IsNull(Trim(rstSQLquery.Fields("Created").Value)) Then
'    Else
'        frmCommentsView.ListBox1.List(ListCnt, 0) = Format(Trim(rstSQLquery.Fields("Created").Value), "YYMMDD HHMM")
'    End If
'    If IsNull(Trim(rstSQLquery.Fields("Comments").Value)) Then
'    Else
'        frmCommentsView.ListBox1.List(ListCnt, 1) = Trim(rstSQLquery.Fields("Comments").Value)
'    End If
'    If IsNull(Trim(rstSQLquery.Fields("Created_By").Value)) Then
'    Else
'        frmCommentsView.ListBox1.List(ListCnt, 2) = Trim(rstSQLquery.Fields("Created_By").Value)
'    End If
'    rstSQLquery.MoveNext
'    ListCnt = ListCnt + 1
'Wend

rstSQLquery.Close

GetComments = RmkCnt

dbConn.Close
Set rstSQLquery = Nothing
Set dbConn = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Welcome! Since this is functional code looking for an improvement, [codereview.se] would be a better fit for your question.

Comment: Does turning off `Application.ScreenUpdating` speed things up?  How about skipping most of it, and just using `frmCommentsView.ListBox1.List = rstRecordSet.GetRows`?

Comment: @Chronocidal, Thanks.  Unfortunately screenupdating doesn't help and GetRows transposes the data and displays incorrectly and more relevantly doesnt seem to impove the speed at all.  Took about the same. to populate.

Comment: Does `tblRFQ_Comments` have an index on `RFQ_ID` and `Created`?

Comment: Try dumping the records onto a hidden worksheet, then see if [this code helps](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/140995/23788).

Comment: I'd profile the performance of the query itself before I started mucking around with the VBA code. There really isn't anything obvious on the VBA side other than some micro-optimizations.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks for the idea.  Just tried this and its equally slow so I guess its the query speed not he ListBox connection.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  Now that I know it was the query method, I changed approaches.  I used native excel data connection to SQL table to dump data into hidden worksheet.